# SQL Server 2012: Moving columns based on the logic

Tags: sql-server, case, coalesce

I have a Table1

```
(Payee_ID INT,
BOX1 VARCHAR(2) NULL, -- possible value only AA
BOX2 VARCHAR(2) NULL, -- possible value only BB
BOX3 VARCHAR(2) NULL, -- possible value only CC
BOX4 VARCHAR(2) NULL) -- possible value only DD
```

Table1 Values:

```
1, NULL, ‘BB’, NULL, ‘DD’
2, ‘AA’, NULL, NULL, ‘DD’
3, NULL, ‘BB’, ‘CC’, ‘DD’
4, ‘AA’, ‘BB’, NULL, ‘DD’
5, ‘AA’, ‘BB’, ‘CC’, ‘DD’ and so on..
```

I have created another table2

```
(Payee_ID INT,
BOX1 VARCHAR(2), --AA
BOX2 VARCHAR(2), --BB
BOX3 VARCHAR(2), --CC
BOX4 VARCHAR(2)) --DD
```

Now populate this table using Table1 but the rule is that if Box1 is null then use Box2’s value for Box1 and so on. So, the expected output is :

```
Payee_ID        Box1   Box2   Box3    Box4
1,              ‘BB’,  ‘DD’,  ’’ ,     ’’
2,              ‘AA’,  ‘DD’,  ’’ ,     ’’
3,              ‘BB’,  ‘CC’,  ‘DD’,    ‘’
4,              ‘AA’,  ‘BB’,  ‘DD’,    ‘’
5,              ‘AA’,  ‘BB’,  ‘CC’,    ‘DD’
```

Comment: This sounds like something you should be doing in the presentation layer and not in the database

Comment: For Payee_ID 1 why is BOX4 blank? Shouldn't it be DD? and Wouldn't Box3 be DD?

Comment: @scsimon: No, That's what the requirement is. If the previous boxes are empty, move the data from the columns where we have data. so, for payee1, since box1 is null and box2 is BB, BB is moved to box1 and so on..

Comment: Then use an update statement,  create a view, but my all that is holy do not recreate DDL on the fly. By the way, you can run updates via CTEs. :)

Comment: @clifton_h : Can you add a sample of how you would do it?

Comment: This just isn't how data works. I would think you could unpivot the columns and then pivot them back again. Still not something i would want to do in the database.

Comment: @SeanLange : I totally agree but that's how the current system is designed and they want to do it the same way. They have a crazy complicated SP just to handle what I asked in requirements. One should'nt do this in DB and if one absolutely have to, then there should be a simpler way..

Comment: Wait, first of all, I think the last answer is closest to what you want. Basically, you wish to move horizontally all of the values so that they read Left to right with any missing values essentially pushed to the rightmost of the columns? If that is true, the solution is simple. (I did read this via my phone)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out... though I still think you shouldn't do this in the DB

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#thisTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #thisTest

SELECT
1 as ID, NULL as BOX1, 'BB' as BOX2, NULL as BOX3, 'DD' as BOX4
INTO #thisTest
UNION ALL
SELECT
2, 'AA', NULL, NULL, 'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT
3, NULL, 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT
4, 'AA', 'BB', NULL, 'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT
5, 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'


SELECT * from #thisTest
select
ID, 
CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL THEN COALESCE(BOX2,BOX3,BOX4) ELSE BOX1 END AS BOX1,
CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL AND BOX2 IS NULL THEN BOX4 WHEN BOX1 IS NULL THEN COALESCE(BOX3,BOX4) ELSE COALESCE(BOX2,BOX3,BOX4)  END AS BOX2,
CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL AND BOX2 IS NULL THEN NULL WHEN (BOX1 IS NULL OR BOX2 IS NULL) and BOX3 IS NULL THEN NULL WHEN  BOX1 IS NULL OR BOX2 IS NULL THEN COALESCE(BOX3,BOX4) ELSE BOX4 END AS BOX3,
CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL or BOX2 IS NULL OR BOX3 IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE BOX4 END AS BOX4
from 
#thisTest
```

Comment: This just demonstrates what a horrible idea this is to do in the database. It is close but doesn't quite produce the desired output. Look at payee_ID 5. :)

Comment: Add the following to table and your code is not producing correct results: 
UNION ALL
SELECT
6, NULL, NULL, 'CC', 'DD'

Comment: Payee_ID 5 is actually correct! The problem is when you add payee_ID 6 with the above combination.

Comment: No. PayeeID 5 returns AA, BB, DD, DD. There is no CC.

Comment: @user3294322 had one more error, should be good now, as in correct, though not suggested.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#thisTest') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #thisTest

SELECT
1 as ID, NULL as BOX1, 'BB' as BOX2, NULL as BOX3, 'DD' as BOX4
INTO #thisTest
UNION ALL
SELECT
2, 'AA', NULL, NULL, 'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT
3, NULL, 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT
4, 'AA', 'BB', NULL, 'DD'
UNION ALL
SELECT
5, 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD'
UNION ALL 
SELECT 6, NULL, NULL, 'CC', 'DD'

SELECT * from #thisTest
select
ID, 
CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL THEN COALESCE(BOX2,BOX3,BOX4) ELSE BOX1 END AS BOX1,

CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL AND BOX2 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(BOX3,BOX4)
     WHEN BOX1 IS NULL AND BOX2 IS NULL THEN BOX4 
     ELSE COALESCE(BOX2,BOX3,BOX4)  END AS BOX2,

CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NULL AND BOX2 IS NULL AND BOX3 IS NULL THEN BOX4 
     WHEN BOX1 IS NOT NULL AND BOX2 IS NOT NULL THEN COALESCE(BOX3,BOX4)
     ELSE '' END AS BOX3,

CASE WHEN BOX1 IS NOT NULL AND BOX2 IS NOT NULL AND BOX3 IS NOT NULL THEN BOX4 ELSE '' END AS BOX4

from 
#thisTest
```

Comment: @scsimon Yes, It does.. Thanks :)

Comment: Glad I could help out. I'm happy I got it mostly right and was helpful

Answer (score 0):

I will simply assume the #thisTest table is populated as it in the examples above. No need to duplicate that code.

```
WITH workTable as (
    SELECT
        ID,
        ISNULL(BOX1, '') + ISNULL(BOX2, '') + ISNULL(BOX3, '') + ISNULL(BOX4, '') AS Boxes 
    FROM #thisTest
    )
INSERT INTO Table2 (
    Payee_id,
    Box1,
    Box2,
    Box3,
    Box4,
    )
SELECT 
    ID,
    ISNULL(SUBSTRING(Boxes, 1, 1), ''),
    ISNULL(SUBSTRING(Boxes, 2, 1), ''),
    ISNULL(SUBSTRING(Boxes, 3, 1), ''),
    ISNULL(SUBSTRING(Boxes, 4, 1), '')
FROM workTable
```

My coding philosophy includes code simplicity. If this was orders of magnitude slower than the other options, I wouldn't use it, but if not, this will perform what you need without multiple checks of which BOXn values are null.

Note that this basic form works with little change even if you have 20 BOX values to compact, whereas a multiple condition check logic will grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

@Laughing.Vergil is on the right track, even if his syntax is a bit off ;)

While not posted in your question, I will answer this question using `CTE` once in the `JOIN` itself and also directly. `:D`

If I understand you correctly, you want all of the values to be pushed to the left side of the row with all NULL values to the right. I will opt to take @Laughing.Vergil's idea since if the known values are stable length, there is no reason the code has to be terribly complicated. i.e. `LEN(Box1) = 2`

In this example, I use the first table you defined and will imagine that the constraints in the application fails in order to exemplify the `CTE` operations.

```
CREATE TABLE #Example (Payee_ID  INT,
                            BOX1 VARCHAR(2) NULL,
                            BOX2 VARCHAR(2) NULL,
                            BOX3 VARCHAR(2) NULL,
                            BOX4 VARCHAR(2) NULL)
INSERT INTO #Example(Payee_ID, BOX1, BOX2, BOX3, BOX4)
VALUES    (1, NULL, 'BB', NULL, 'DD')
        , (2, 'AA', NULL, NULL, 'DD')
        , (3, NULL, 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')
        , (4, 'AA', 'BB', NULL, 'DD')
        , (5, 'AA', 'BB', 'CC', 'DD')
        , (6, NULL, 'CB', NULL, 'DD') -- the bad input
;WITH C as (
    SELECT
        Payee_ID
      , ISNULL(Box1, '') + ISNULL(Box2, '') + ISNULL(Box3, '') + ISNULL(Box4, '') AS BOX
    FROM #Example
    )
UPDATE A
  SET 
     BOX1 =  IIF(SUBSTRING(Box, 1, 2) = '', NULL, SUBSTRING(Box, 1, 2))
   , BOX2 = IIF(SUBSTRING(Box, 3, 2) = '', NULL, SUBSTRING(Box, 3, 2))
   , BOX3 = IIF(SUBSTRING(Box, 5, 2) = '', NULL, SUBSTRING(Box, 5, 2))
   , BOX4 = IIF(SUBSTRING(Box, 7, 2) = '', NULL, SUBSTRING(Box, 7, 2))
FROM #Example A
INNER JOIN C ON C.Payee_ID = A.Payee_ID
```

**Results**

```
Payee_ID    BOX1    BOX2    BOX3    BOX4
1           BB      DD      NULL    NULL
2           AA      DD      NULL    NULL
3           BB      CC      DD      NULL
4           AA      BB      DD      NULL
5           AA      BB      CC      DD
6           CB      ED      NULL    NULL
```

Now the exciting part. Updating/Deleting from a table using `CTE`s. For arguments sake, lets assume only the first Box can ever be invalid due to the way the application works.

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *
             FROM #Example2
             WHERE BOX1 NOT IN  ( (LEFT(Box1, 1) ) 
                                + (LEFT(Box1, 1) ) ) )
DELETE FROM CTE
```

**Final Results**

```
Payee_ID    BOX1    BOX2    BOX3    BOX4
1           BB      DD      NULL    NULL
2           AA      DD      NULL    NULL
3           BB      CC      DD      NULL
4           AA      BB      DD      NULL
5           AA      BB      CC      DD
```

While this was very silly, I hope you can see how the tables behind the `CTE` are affected, which is kinda cool.

Cheers,

Comment: Note that I also presumed Payee_ID has only one row associated.